# cakephp validation on multiple dates

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.3

I have a form which have add more functionality. user can enter their multiple education. now I want to add a validation rule for the below condition

> **if user started their first education in 2006 and completed in 2008**
>   **then he can not enter second education starting date 2008 or before**
>   **that**

here are my validation rules

```
 /**
     * Validation
     *
     * @var array
     * @access public
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'degree_type_id' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'is_unique_degree' => array(
                'rule' => 'is_unique_degree',
                'message' => 'You have added same course multiple time.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'college_hospital' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'size' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 255),
                'message' => 'This field must be no larger than 255 characters long.'
            ),
        ),
        'year_passing' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'start_date' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'dateRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
                'message' => 'Enter a valid date in MM/YYYY format.',
                'allowEmpty' => true
            ),
            'validateDuration' => array(
                'rule' => 'validateDuration',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'end_date' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'dateRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
                'message' => 'Enter a valid date in MM/YYYY format.',
                'allowEmpty' => true
            ),
            'validateEndDate' => array(
                'rule' => 'validateEndDate',
                'message' => 'End date should be greater than start date.',
                'allowEmpty' => true
            )
        ),
    );
```

This is what I try and got success only for validating future date condition

```
 public function validateDuration() {
        $startDate = $this->data['DoctorEducation']['start_date'];
        $endDate = $this->data['DoctorEducation']['end_date'];
        if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) < strtotime($startDate)) {
            return __('Education duration will not be future date');
        }

        if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) < strtotime($endDate)) {
            return __('Education duration will not be future date');
        }
       //pr($this->data);
        return true;
    }
```

let me know if you want any other information.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a special rule. Your requirement basically comes down to "new start date has to be higher than last end date". I'm sure you can code that judging by your snippets above.

Comment: facing issue in doing so that's why I posted here.

Comment: So why don't you post what you did and what the issue is?

Comment: I already post each and every thing. let me know what else you want

Comment: Sorry I have no answer to your problem. But I suggest to enhance your question to make it easyer for others to help you: Please show only the relevant code, e.g. remove all **unrelevant** code, tags/classes and fields from the model and form (like in model 'collage_hospital' or in the form 'class="col-md-6"' etc. and the many div tags...) And a second note: Why sould it be wrong to start the second education in the same year you ended your first education? E.g. if you have exams in spring and get your degree in summer you can start studying in august...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you should have a User model with a hasMany association with DoctorEducation. One approach could be to define in the User model:

```
var $usedDates = array;
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    $this->usedDates = array();
}
```

then the validation rules for the DoctorEducation model could use it:

```
public function validateStart( $dataToValidate ) {
    foreach($this->ParentModel->usedDates as $usedDate) {
        // Perform whatever check you need to ensure periods
        // don't overlap and return errors
    }
    $key = count($this->ParentModel->usedDates);
    $this->ParentModel->usedDates[$key]['start_date'] = $dataToValidate['start_date'];
    return true;
}

public function validateEnd( $dataToValidate ) {
    foreach($this->ParentModel->usedDates as $usedDate) {
        // Perform whatever check you need to ensure periods
        // don't overlap and return errors
    }
    $key = count($this->ParentModel->usedDates) - 1;
    $this->ParentModel->usedDates[$key]['end_date'] = $dataToValidate['end_date'];
    return true;
}
```

The above assumes you will be saving the User model **together** with the DoctorEducation model.

Comment: If DoctorEducation is your child model, perhaps Doctor is your parent model ?

Comment: Of course. Sorry... to translate my "parent v/s child" into CakePHP jargon:
The Doctor model should have a OneToMany association with DoctorEducation.

Comment: no, there is no doctor model. but user model have  `public $hasMany = array(
        'DoctorEducation' => array('dependent' => true),`

Comment: I edited the answer with the correct naming conventions